# MQ Failure to send message - MQJE046: Unsupported codeset

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm using MQ v. 6.x.
Usually i can send and receive messages just fine. However, for some messages I get a 'MQJE046: Unsupported codeset' exception.
It seeme to be related to size, as i could reproduce the issue with message made of chars 0-9 in length greater then 32218 bytes.

```
    javax.jms.JMSException: MQJMS1016: an internal error has occurred. Please contact your system administrator. Detail: com.ibm.mqservices.MQInternalException: MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code 2, Reason 2195
    MQJE046: Unsupported codeset : 0
                    at com.ibm.mq.jms.services.ConfigEnvironment.newException(ConfigEnvironment.java:586)
                    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQMessageProducer.sendInternal(MQMessageProducer.java:1693)
                    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQMessageProducer.send(MQMessageProducer.java:1056)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it a multithreaded app? MQTopicPublisher or MQQueueSender cannot be shared between threads and this message could be caused from sharing this objects between threads.

Refer to [this mqseries.net thread](http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=20774&highlight=unsupported%20codeset)

Comment: The implementation is thread safe and this happens in test conditions when there is a single thread

Comment: Well, I don't set it explicitly... should it be set? for most messages there is no issue as it is, only for large enough messages...